# styling div classes on css

Tags: html, css

im learning the box models so i created three div classes and styled them but nothing changed after styling. Is it dat u cant style a div class unless it has a sub element like a **p** tag ,**h1** tag and the likes. I tried styling ordinary divs and it worked just this div classes...here is the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css"> 

        body{
            background-color: grey;
            }
        .1{
            background-color:green;
            width: 250px;
            margin:auto;
          }

        .2{
            background-color: yellow;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates sint inventore, provident neque, dolore saepe asperiores dolorum laborum alias exercitationem molestiae repellat necessitatibus at in dolorem tenetur blanditiis. Doloremque, id!</div>

<div class="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus illo, accusantium! Optio quisquam incidunt odio repellat, quis illum officia suscipit pariatur quasi ullam. Voluptatibus perspiciatis in nihil vero reprehenderit corporis.</div>

<div class="3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolor voluptate voluptas molestiae nesciunt et illo nobis atque quasi blanditiis quas nihil veniam qui debitis, mollitia sapiente eos animi cupiditate.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note. We're all professionals here and using proper words, grammar and punctuation are important when asking questions. You might wish to bear that in mind,

Answer (score 1):

Class can't start with a number, this is why your styles aren't working.

```
.one{
    background-color:green;  
    width: 250px; 
    margin:auto;
}

<div class="one">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you have issues with your class name you can not set your class name only numeric please change class name try below code it will helps you.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

<style type="text/css"> 
    body{
        background-color: grey;
        }
    .div1{
        background-color:green;
        width: 250px;
        margin:auto;
      }

    .div2{
        background-color: yellow;
    }

</style>
<div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates sint inventore, provident neque, dolore saepe asperiores dolorum laborum alias exercitationem molestiae repellat necessitatibus at in dolorem tenetur blanditiis. Doloremque, id!</div>

<div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus illo, accusantium! Optio quisquam incidunt odio repellat, quis illum officia suscipit pariatur quasi ullam. Voluptatibus perspiciatis in nihil vero reprehenderit corporis.</div>

<div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolor voluptate voluptas molestiae nesciunt et illo nobis atque quasi blanditiis quas nihil veniam qui debitis, mollitia sapiente eos animi cupiditate.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes names must begin with a letter. Some browsers may erroneously support them, though.

From [CSS Synatx module level](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#characters)

> "In CSS3, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors (see [SELECT] [or is this still true])) can contain only the
>   characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus
>   the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit
>   or a hyphen followed by a digit. They can also contain escaped
>   characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next
>   item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?"
>   or "B\26 W\3F". (See [UNICODE310] and [ISO10646].)"

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>   
<style type="text/css">     
    body{
        background-color: grey;
        }
    .div1{
        background-color:green;
        width: 250px;
        margin:auto;
      }    
    .div2{
        background-color: yellow;
    }   

</style>
<div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates sint inventore, provident neque, dolore saepe asperiores dolorum laborum alias exercitationem molestiae repellat necessitatibus at in dolorem tenetur blanditiis. Doloremque, id!</div>

<div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus illo, accusantium! Optio quisquam incidunt odio repellat, quis illum officia suscipit pariatur quasi ullam. Voluptatibus perspiciatis in nihil vero reprehenderit corporis.</div>    

<div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolor voluptate voluptas molestiae nesciunt et illo nobis atque quasi blanditiis quas nihil veniam qui debitis, mollitia sapiente eos animi cupiditate.</div>
```